# How to get files from server using ftp function in php

Tags: php

I want to get files from a remote server using ftp function in php. I use the ftp_nlist method to get the files but the problem is when I loop through it it contains full path with the file name. I want only file names

```
<?php    
$ftp_server = "host.com"; 

    $ftp_connection = ftp_connect($ftp_server) 
    or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server"); 
    $ftp_username="user";
    $ftp_userpass ="password";
    $login = ftp_login($ftp_connection, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);
    $path = "mainpath/assets/Template/Top/";
    $contents = ftp_nlist($ftp_connection, $path);

foreach($contents as $key=>$dat) {
echo $contents[$key];
}
?>
```

Which I get the files but the path contains  namemainpath/assets/Template/Top/file.ext

I just want file.ext

Answer (score 0):

You should use [basename](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)

```
foreach( $contents as $key=>$dat ) {
   // To get the filename + extension
   echo basename( $contents[$key] );

   // To get the filename without extension
   $extension = explode( ".", $contents[$key] );
   echo basename( $contents[$key], '.'.$extension[1] );
}
```

Comment: Also have a look at `pathinfo()`